# Difference between "a day" vs "a night"

Tags: word-choice

How much sleep do you need?

I answered

> Six hours a day.

The answer in the English Grammar in Use is

> Six (or other numbers of your choice) hours a night.

Does ~ a night and ~ a day mean the same?  Which sounds more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on context, a day can be either a 24-hour period (as you intended) or the daylight hours/working day. Since we normally have our main period of sleep at night, it sounds more natural to say 'X hours a night' - unless you have already explained that you work a night shift!